# Deducing the return type of an inline static member function in class definition

Tags: c++, c++17, return-type-deduction

I'm trying to create an alias to a return type after an inline function definition to store a member variable. I simplified my situation below (the real type I want to alias is much uglier to type than vector, and the real function more complicated than a one-liner.)

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
struct Test {
    template <typename T>
    static auto GetVector() { return vector<T>(); }

    using VecInt = decltype(GetVector<int>());
    VecInt x;
};
```

However, clang gives me the following error on the `using VecInt` line:

error: function 'GetVector' with deduced return type cannot be used before it is defined.

gcc also gives me a similar error. Strangely, this compiles, although it's not useful in my case:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
struct Test {
    template <typename T>
    static auto GetVector() { return vector<T>(); }

    void dummy() {
        using VecInt = decltype(GetVector<int>());
        VecInt x;
    }
};
```

Is there a way for me to alias after an inline definition? Alternatively, I can move the GetVector() function on top of the struct, and the code will compile. However, I want to contain it there.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking, but are you *perhaps* looking for `auto foo() -> decltype(auto) { ... }` ?

Comment: The compiler would still complain about this line `using VecInt = decltype(GetVector<int>());` I can get `GetVector()` to deduce the return type, but I can't get the deduced return type in the class definition to alias it to store a variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Member function bodies are a [*complete-class context*](http://eel.is/c++draft/class#def:complete-class_context), meaning that the class is regarded as complete there. Within the body of a member function, name lookup can find any other member function or data member of typedef - whether it was declared before the function or after.

Since `GetVector()` has a placeholder type, it needs to wait until the class is complete before instantiating the body and deducing the return type.

But alias declarations are *not* complete-class contexts. You need to figure out what `VecInt` is *at that point*, without having the class being complete yet. Since `GetVector()` needs the class to complete first, this just can't work.

You'll either need to (a) explicitly specify the return type of `GetVector()`, (b) explicitly specify `VecInt`, or (c) move `GetVector()` out of this class (whether making it a free function or moving it to a base class):

```
#include <vector>

struct TestBase {
    template <typename T>
    static auto GetVector() { return std::vector<T>(); }
};

struct Test : TestBase {
    using VecInt = decltype(GetVector<int>());
    VecInt x;
};
```

Comment: Shoudn't a *nested* class work as well? This would at least retain the scope limited to the current class...

Comment: @Aconcagua No, because nested-classes can use members of the enclosing class - so a hypothetical `Test::Inner::GetVector` would still need `Test` to be complete first.

Answer (score 5):

Ever notice how you can call inline-defined member functions from inside of other member functions, even if the callee is farther down the class than the caller? The reason that works is because the compiler takes inlined definitions of member functions and moves the definitions to the bottom of the class, right after the `}` part. So you effectively have an implicit forward declaration.

This is *not* true for type aliases like `using` declarations. These declarations exist exactly where they are in the class; they cannot reference declarations or definitions that come later in the class.

Since the return value of your function cannot be deduced by the declaration alone, and the actual definition (the thing needed to deduce the return value) lives at the end of the class, your `using` alias fails to compile. There's not much you can do about this besides declare the function's return value directly. Or declare the type alias as having the desired type, then have the function use that alias.

Answer (score 0):

Could an intermediate typedef help? Something like:

```
#include <vector>
struct Test
{
    template <typename T>
    using MySimplerType = std::vector<T>;

    template <typename T>
    static auto GetVector() { return MySimplerType<T>(); }

    using VecInt = MySimplerType<int>;
    VecInt x;
};
```

Comment: It would work in this case but in my real case I have a template non-type function with `ifconstexpr` inside that returns different `std::boyer_moore_searcher`s that takes different lambda functions for hash and comparison based on the non-type template argument. I was hoping to create an `std::variant` of these, but based on other answers, it looks like my only solution is to make the function non-member.